# Update 2 tables to join them with stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-update, inner-join

I'm trying to update this 2 tables :

1. `tblProducts` : PID, PName, PPrice, PSelPrice, PCategoryID, PDescription, image, featured
2. `tblCategories` : CatID, CatName

But it can't save it. So there is error...

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[procUpdateProducts]
    @PID int,
    @PName nvarchar(50),
    @PPrice money,
    @PSelPrice money,
    @PCategoryID int,
    @PDescription nvarchar(MAX),
    @image nvarchar(MAX),
    @featured nvarchar(10)
AS   
BEGIN    
    UPDATE tblProducts
    SET PID = @PID, 
        PName = @PName, 
        PPrice = @PPrice, 
        PSelPrice = @PSelPrice, 
        PCategoryID = @PCategoryID,
        PDescription = @PDescription, 
        [image] = @image, 
        featured = @featured
    FROM tblProducts AS p 
    INNER JOIN tblCategories AS c ON p.PCategoryID = c.CatID
    WHERE PID = @PID
END
```

Comment: @marc_s It can't be saved so I don't know where is the error!

Comment: No! Just the update not working.. I'm using it in visual studio asp.net that's why...

Comment: So you do not get any error - the code just isn't doing what you want it to do ..... how are you calling this from ASP.NET ?? Can you make a note of the parameter values, and then try to run it from SQL Server Management Studio - do you get an error there?? Or same - it just doesn't do anything?? Have you checked if there is any data for that `@PID` you're using??

Comment: Could you please check whether there is a value in the table for which you are updating or whether you are passing the correct Id as a parameter

Comment: You're probably missing a row in one of the tables, maybe category.

Comment: You cannot update two tables in the same statement, if that is what you are trying to do

Answer (score 0):

Hope that following query will work!

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[procUpdateProducts]
@PID int,
@PName nvarchar(50),
@PPrice money,
@PSelPrice money,
@PCategoryID int,
@PDescription nvarchar(MAX),
@image nvarchar(MAX),
@featured nvarchar(10)
AS   
BEGIN    
    UPDATE p
    SET p.PID = @PID, 
        p.PName = @PName, 
        p.PPrice = @PPrice, 
        p.PSelPrice = @PSelPrice, 
        p.PCategoryID = @PCategoryID,
        p.PDescription = @PDescription, 
        p.[image] = @image, 
        p.featured = @featured
    FROM tblProducts AS p 
    INNER JOIN tblCategories AS c ON p.PCategoryID = c.CatID
    WHERE p.PID = @PID
END
```